# printing hidden data through jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have the following code where for display I want to hide the detail code and only should during print:

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <span style="font-size: 1.25em;">
                <strong>#dateformat(startdate, "mm-dd-yyyy")# - #dateformat(enddate, "mm-dd-yyyy")#</strong>
            </span><br/><br/>
            #fullLeft(stripHTML(details),30)#
            </div>
            <div style="display:none;" class="completedata" align="left">
                #details#
            </div>
        <li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

```js
$(window).load(function() {
    $('li').each(function () {
        $(this).css({
            "page-break-after": "always"
        });
        $(".completedata").css('display','block');
        window.print();
    });
});
```

It shows the printing code on load with hidden display data, but when i cancel the printing command, it keeps the hidden div displays as `block` and shows in the display screen too.

Comment: Your question is not clear at all, but it sounds like you should be using a print stylesheet, not hacking at the DOM when someone prints a page.

Comment: you're calling window.print() inside a loop. which means you're triggering a print job for EVERY `<li>` on your page.

Comment: it is like, to display on screen, i want to hide the detailed description, but while printing i want to show that hidden content code and when i cancel the printing, it should revert back to the same old display way

Comment: @Marc - That is right, that is the requirement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right way to do this is to use `@media print`:

```
.completedata { display: none; }    
@media print 
{
    .completedata { display: block !important; }
}
```

```js
$("button").on("click", function() {
  window.print();
});
```

```css
.completedata {
  color: #e74c3c;
}
.completedata {
  display: none;
}
@media print {
  .completedata {
    display: block !important;
  }
  button { display: none; }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Assumenda impedit sapiente atque quas aliquam a voluptate obcaecati saepe incidunt itaque eligendi sequi optio delectus similique laborum unde sint consectetur magnam?</p>

<p class="completedata">I appear only when printing the page!</p>

<button>Print me</button>
```